# How can I read a txt file with µ as delimiter?

Tags: python, r, pandas, readr

I have a txt file which I would like to read in either Python or R (does not matter).

I tried in R to change the locale with readr package, which can read the µ properly when changing to e.g.

```
data<- read_delim("./weirdfile.txt","µ", escape_double = FALSE, locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), 
    trim_ws = TRUE)
```

However the above solution does not use "µ" as delimiter.

Comment: instead of `"µ"` try `mu` with no quotes. R has greek letters built in

Comment: I tried in multiple combinations (with readr gui and in console) no success there. In the gui they say the character is invalid and in console it does not parse.

Comment: or  "find and replace all" in a text editor and use a different character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as the code for mu:

```
CSV file:
clientμdatetime
abcμabc

DELIMITER = '\u03BC'
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=DELIMITER)
print(df)

  client datetime
0    abc      abc
```